# How to make .rdlc report with C#/WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report, reportviewer

I want to know how to generate reports in WPF app. I found some tutorial in `MSDN`. They say that i need to add new reference to
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms`, but I don't have such thing on list. I want to design report in Visual Studio and open it with code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project -> Add -> References. Then in the search bar search for Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms. This will allow you to add a report viewer which will display the form you create.